# examples of I-V-II-VI in any type of song?

Tags: chord-progressions

anyone have examples of I-V-II-VI being used? im pretty sure its just secondary dominants leading into eachother and it has a very nice sound.

Comment: I'm sure that going in the opposite direction is more common.

Comment: Hi! Questions for which the answers would just be lists of examples are not on topic here. I suggest editing to ask more *about* this progression.

Answer (score 1):

Since these are dominants stacking  as `I V V(V) V(V(V))`, functional harmony would expect these to sound increasingly tense.

Let's say this is in C Major. Then the chords are `C G D A`. Another way to view these might be as `IV I V II` in the key of G major. There, the II chord, A, acts as a passing chord between the D and the C, as we can voice lead smoothly.

```
( in no particular voice order )
A    A    G
F#   E    E
D    C#   C
Dmaj Amaj Cmaj
```

Or is there something about the progression that makes this analysis not line up?